# Asymptotic of gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I would like to obtain the asymptotic behavior as $x \rightarrow -\infty$ of the following function $f(x)$:

$$f(x)= c e^{\frac{a x^2}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^x  e^{-\frac{a \eta^2}{2}} d \eta$$

where $a~\text{ and}~ c$ are constants. How can the asymptotic be obtained? I tried Taylor expansions for the exponential and then integrating that but I don't quite understand it.

Comment: Is $a\lt0$? Otherwise the given integral diverges.

Comment: A potential method to compute the limit is L'hopitals, treating $ce^{-ax^2/2}$ as the denominator

Comment: Maybe my question is badly formulated: I am looking for the asymptote in this limit

Comment: @Andrea Have you possibly missed a minus sign in the powers? As Peter says, the integral is divergent otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Then the integral is equal to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}ce^{\frac{ax^{2}}{2}}\left(1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}x\right)\right)$. You can use $\operatorname{erf}(x)\in1-\frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}x}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{-2}\right)\right)$ to asymptotically expand $f$.

Comment: Sorry I'd misread your question and gave the expansion for $x\to+\infty$. For $x\to-\infty$, you want $\operatorname{erf}(x)\in\color{red}{-1}-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}x}\ldots$.

Comment: What about the integral $\int_0^x e^{-a \eta^2 /2} d\eta$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$? How would it be using the erf(x) function? @Jam

Comment: You can deduce that from my comment and the definition of the error function.

Comment: @Jam I don't understand where does the 1+ come from in the definition of the erf function. I checked wikipedia but couldn't understand how you obtained it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: @Andrea Use integration by substitution with $u=\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}\eta$ to get the same integrand as $\operatorname{erf}(x)$. But $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ is defined by the integral from $0$, while yours was the integral from $-\infty$ so split this into the two integrals $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{v}=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}+\int\limits_{0}^{v}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply integration by parts:
$$e^{a x^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^x -\frac 1 {a \eta} d(e^{-a \eta^2/2}) =
-\frac 1 {a \eta} e^{a x^2/2 - a \eta^2/2} \bigg \rvert_{\eta = -\infty}^x -
e^{a x^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^x \frac 1 {a \eta^2} e^{-a \eta^2} d\eta$$
and show that the second term on the rhs is asymptotically smaller, or you can apply Laplace's method:
$$e^{a x^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-a \eta^2/2} d\eta =
\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-a x u - a u^2/2} du \sim
e^{-a u^2/2} \bigg \rvert_{u = 0} \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-a x u} du.$$